# CORS issue is related with packages version?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a react.js app with react@17.x
While integrating the API, I am getting a `CORS` issue.
I think the `CORS` issue should be resolved in API side.
But someone told me it can be resolved in react.js by upgrading some versions.
Looks like he wants me to upgrade `node`, `npm`, or `node_modules`.
Is it possible?

Comment: No, you can't, it's a backend concept. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors

Answer (score 0):

CORS issue happens when the backend doesn't allow you to hit their end points from your frontend applications end points. You need check you backend code.